# Why are my flex items not taking up the full width of my flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scroll, containers

I have one big flex container and two small flex containers inside it. The two small flex containers have two flex items each. The problem I am facing is that the two flex items inside the second small flex container are not taking up the full width of the second small flex container.

[Image of one big flex container containing two small flex containers each containing two flex items. A black arrow points to a red column streak of pixels in the second small flex container, the red column streak of pixels is at the right-end of the second small flex container. The code is rendered on Safari Version 16.6.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSNno.jpg)

```css
.BIG-flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.SMALL-flex-container {
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.flex-item {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.flex-item-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.flex-item-2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="BIG-flex-container">
  <div class="SMALL-flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-1">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="SMALL-flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-1">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hiding overflow does remove the column streak but keeps my second small flex container from being scrollable. I also used JavaScript to programmatically scroll the second small flex container while overflow was hidden, but the streak returned! What I am expecting is that my flex items fill my second small flex container perfectly with the background color of the second small flex container not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Artifacts such as these do occur from time to time. They are generally visible in some viewport configurations and not others. If you resize your browser window, I think you’ll find that this artifact is present at some sizes, but not all sizes. Browsers calculate widths and heights in fractional pixels, but when it comes time to render, the values have to be rounded to whole pixels. We have known about the issue [for years](https://johnresig.com/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/), and there’s no solution. Just ignore it, there’s nothing wrong with your code. Minimise the impact by carefully choosing background colours.

I would like to suggest an unrelated improvement to your code, though. Rather than a combination of `min-width: 100%` and `max-width: 100%` to prevent flex items from shrinking, a cleaner solution is to set `width: 100%` and `flex-shrink: 0`.

```css
.BIG-flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.SMALL-flex-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.flex-item-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.flex-item-2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="BIG-flex-container">
  <div class="SMALL-flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-1">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="SMALL-flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-1">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```